# Sharing formatted reports over the mail in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins, allure, html-reports-jenkins

***What's Working*** - We are currently using [`testng`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-xml-reports) emailable format and [`allure`](https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example) to generate formatted reports for our current test execution. These are working fine with our local. The `/target/report` structure can be seen in the image to depict 2 different folders for allure(/site) and **testng(/surefire)** reports respectively : 
[image]

---

***Trying to*** - While we are trying to implement a CI using [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) using the same steps as in our local, the tests are executed fine and the respective reports are getting generated as well.

Using [TestNG](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin) plugin
and specifying the pattern `**/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml` works just fine to display the testNG result graph.

Also using the [Email ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin I can attach the .html reports to the mail sent to the recipients specifying the attachment field details as : 
`**/target/surefire-reports/emailable-report.html, **/target/surefire-reports/index.html`

---

***What doesn't work*** - We end up getting emails with HTML reports but these are not formatted, probably because all the CSS linked to these are left behind. Is there a way to overcome this?

---

***Note -*** Have tried these:

1. Attaching all the .css files along with .html file in attachments but, one that's brute force and second it still doesn't work.
2. One way also is to `scp` the report (/target) directory to another host from Jenkins instance and share the path of the reports on that machine over the email notification and get the *formatted* reports shared. But then this needs an additional resource and dependency on it, that we would want to avoid.
3. While posting this, I see an [HTML publisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) plugin that seems to be doing something similar. Tried installing the same and use it. But I am assuming since we are using **`Jenkins 2.6`** and the plugin note reads

> Starting in versions 1.625.3 and 1.641, Jenkins restricted what kind
>   of content could be displayed when serving static files. This can
>   impact how HTML files archived using this plugin are displayed. See
>   Configuring Content Security Policy for more information.

We are not getting the option to `Publish HTML Reports` in the post build actions.

---

Any suggestions are more than welcome and please do ask for any more information required over this.

***Edit*** : Adding to the Note 2 above, the Jenkins instances used in our setup are docker slaves, apparently making the reports or targets generated not being persistent.

Comment: If you want to get over the CSP problem, you will have to relaunch jenkins with specific setup.  You can just specify a link in your email then to the archived folder - would be as good as one click - just a quick way to get around the problem, if the report is just meant for developers.

Comment: @niharika_neo Could you please elaborate on what the intent above is.

Comment: All I am suggesting is you build up a link to your index.html (hopefully archived), say jenkins/yourjob/buildnumber/archives/index.html and get it in the content of the email.  Your email would have the emailable-report attached with the summary and for more details, refer this link.  In my previous stint, I had even parsed the console log to get a summary of data in the email itself.  x Passed, y Failed.  For detailed report, click here. - Hope it clarifies.  Just approaching the problem in another way.

Comment: @niharika_neo does that not require me to scp reports to a machine and try linking them in the mails sent?

Comment: Nope build your jenkins link (eg. protocol://jenkins/yourjob/10/archives/index.html).  It should be archived for sure(use post build archival for that), so that you get the data for the test you ran.  and then in your email_ext add a hyperlink to index.html.  Ofcourse if you have login enabled then folks would have to login to see the report.

Comment: @niharika_neo Probably the solution you are guiding to needs a master configuration of jenkins. We are currently working with docker configurations of it which leads to inconsistency of accessing the path as you mentioned. And for the same reason we don't want to scp or cp the files to access them.

Comment: Your slaves are docker containers? So the reports and everything goes with the container - is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: @niharika_neo true, we wouldn't persist them once we are done with the job execution.

Comment: Hmm "you wouldn't persist" would mean you don't want to or you are still to figure out how? :)

Comment: @niharika_neo If we have them on mail shared, I wouldn't need to persist them on any storage. Thats what the question is about.

Comment: Agreed.  If you want to persist "only" through emails then yes zipping is the only option - which can ofcourse bring its own set of problems if there is mail size limits and big reports - then you need to get your own code of the reporter et al.  Was just trying to simplify your problem

Comment: How about just inlining the CSS into a style tag in a post-build action? Searching for _inline css into html_ e.g. yields [this node program](https://github.com/jonkemp/inline-css) but maybe there are others that suit your setup in a better way.

Comment: @StefanHanke apologies for being late on this, but could you share an example of inlinging css while generating the test reports. Also I was concerned over the number of files this might include while processing. Would it be feasible as well to do so with more than 100 css files let's say?

Comment: @nullpointer I have no example to share, this is just an idea that could help deleting the external link. Come to think of it, if size poses a problem, maybe you could minify the CSS before it is inlined into the page, or strip unnecessary CSS classes, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can consider doing.

**Option 1**

1. Build an implementation for [IExecutionListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IExecutionListener.html) wherein you create the logic to basically zip up all the reports that you want and have it sent as an e-mail.
2. Wire in this listener and that should take care.

PS : Currently implementations of IExecutionListener are invoked "before" the report generation phase. I have changed this as part of [this](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/commit/28c1bbd966fb4bb0eeefe786d1f58b47f5cb7599) commit. So if you would like to go ahead with this approach then you might want to wait till TestNG goes out with a new release (should happen in a couple of days )

**Option 2**

- Build a wrapper reporter (which implements [IReporter](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IReporter.html)) and wire in ONLY this reporter.
- Within this reporter, you explicitly instantiate all the reporters that you would like to be called in for your reporting phase. See below for a possible sample.

```java
public class ChainedReporter implements IReporter {

    private List<IReporter> reporters = new ArrayList<>;

    public ChainedReporter() {
        reporters.add(new FooReporter() );//Here FooReporter is a custom reporter. Replace it with yours.
        reporters.add(new BarReporter() );//Here BarReporter is a custom reporter. Replace it with yours.
    }
    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
        for (IReporter reporter : reporters) {
            reporter.generateReport(xmlSuites, suites, outputDirectory);
        }
        //By now we have ensured that all the reporting logic has been triggered and we have reports generated.
        zipReports(); //  This method would take care of creating zipped files of all the reports.
        emailReports(); // This emthod would take care of emailing the actual reports.

    }
}
```

Comment: This might be coming in late, but has the changes been released? Also though I can see making code end changes might solve this. But I am keen to find an option within Jenkins(plugin/scripting) to share the existing generated report.